# How I can resolve this problem (Class<SpringJUnit4ClassRunner> cannot be resolved to a type)?

Tags: spring, maven

I realized a simple projetc using spring and maven, my project contains an interface and 3 classes and the pom.xml file

Interface : `CompactDisc.java`

3 classes : 
`SgtPeppers.java` that implements the `CompactDisc` interface

`CDPlayersConfig.java` is an empty class and contains the annotations of automatic scan

`CDPlayersTest.java` is a test class to test if the spring container works.

**My problem is with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and @ContextConfiguration(classes=CDPlayersConfig.class)**, Eclipse suggests this proposition for the first annotation **Class cannot be resolved to a type** and it doesn't understand the second annotation.

You find here the code :

**CompactDisc.java**

```
     package soundsystem; 
    public interface CompactDisc {
        void play();
}
```

**SgtPeppers.java**

```
package soundsystem;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SgtPeppers implements CompactDisc{

    private String title = "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band";
    private String artist = "The Beatles";

    public void play() {

        System.out.println("Playing " + title + "by"+ artist);
    }

}
```

**CDPlayersConfig.java**

```
package soundsystem;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CDPlayersConfig {

}
```

**CDPlayerTest.java**

```
package soundsystem;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.SpringJtaSynchronizationAdapter;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)//Here is my problem
@ContextConfiguration(classes=CDPlayersConfig.class)//Here is my problem
public class CDPlayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;

    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(cd);
    }
}
```

**Dependencies im the pom file**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Eclipse

Right Click on your Project

Select Maven

Select Update Project

Tick

`Update project config from pom.xml`

`Refresh workspace`

`Clean projects`

After doing that the required libraries should be available to Eclipse and you should be able to import the classes as required.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see

```
 import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
 import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
```

in your import section. Also, maybe you should use SpringRunner.class instead of SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class

Comment: When I click the button to import the package, it gives me this message :  Class cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I'm not sure about the button, since I do not use Eclipse much. Have you tried to just copy paste imports from my answer to import section?

Comment: yes, I tried to copy your suggestions, but still same error.

Comment: ok then. You have spring-test version 4.0.5 whereas the latest version is 5.0.6 . Do you have to use version 4? If not, I suggest to replace version in you pom.xml. Also that would be cool to look at you whole pom.xml . You have other dependencies becides those you have posted, right?

Comment: I changed the version of spring-test from 4 to 5, but still the same problem,

Comment: Yes I have other dependencies such as spring-context, soring-tx, dependencies of logging and junit dependencies.

Comment: I have tried reproducing what you have and everything works for me. I have the following inside my pom.xml - spring-context version 5.0.6.RELEASE , spring-test version 5.0.6.RELEASE and junit version 4.12 . Try running tests with pure maven. If that doesn't work, I cant help you unless you post the whole project somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Control+click on the class. Eclipse will open the file. Copy the package name. Create a new import statement and paste the package name + the class name. Problem solved.

If Eclipse does not open the file when you control+click, you don't have it on your class path or imported correctly.

Comment: this solution is not normal, but it worked for me too. Looks like some thing wrong with STS. Ctrl + 1 was unable to resolve it automatically.

Comment: Yes, it's not normal, it's an STS defect workaround for when you need to hit a deadline! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the imports (import org.springframework...) for SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and ContextConfiguration. That's why they are not recognized.

Comment: When I click the button to import the package, it gives me this message : Class cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 0):

You have to add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
```

And then

```
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working in my Gradle project after complete some steps.

1st: Add dependency in build.gradle file ->
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.0.RELEASE'

2nd: Clean Gradle project using IDE or using command prompt -> Open command prompt -> Go to project location c:\gradle_projects\test_gradle>gradlew clean build -> Enter

3rd: Refresh Gradle project -> Open command prompt -> Go to project location c:\gradle_projects\test_gradle>gradlew --refresh-dependencies -> Enter

4th: Go to IDE -> right-click on project name -> Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project
-> finally download jar files and import class